# MS Access: Which keyboard keys to delete Query Object?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

[image]

I'm trying to automate operations in Access and have limited exposure to Access.

While I know a right-click on the query object will delete, I was wondering if we have any keyboard shortcuts.

For example: For Import:
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> through keys can open the Import Dialog Box

I'm looking for such key combinations to delete "Query Objects" and "table objects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Navigation pane, you can click Queries.

Then: *Arrow-Right, Arrow-Down*. Hold *Shift* and press *Arrow-Down* until all items are marked.

Press *Delete*.